# jQuery 'this' keyword in custom methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, this

In lots of cases I have seen the greatness of how jQuery modifies the this keyword to give the object that you would expect to be there actually be there. Great....

However how do you deal with situation where you have custom objects that have custom methods which reference the this keyword but are called thru jQuery.

For example:

```
var myCustomObject = {

    myCustomValue: 1,

    myCustomMethod: function () {
        switch (this.myCustomValue) {
            case ....
        }
    }

};
```

If called using a jQuery callback "this" is now the jQuery "context" and obviously returns undefined for myCustomValue.

I have noticed that I can refer to the instance directly such as

```
switch (myCustomObject.myCustomValue) {}
```

But this seems annoyingly verbose and I wonder if any unexpected side affects could be caused by this...

What is best practice for such scenarios?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it doesn't have to be public:

```
var myCustomObject = new (function()
{
    var myCustomValue = 1;
    this.myCustomMethod = function () {
        switch (myCustomValue) {

        }
    }
})();
```

If it does:

```
var myCustomObject = new (function()
{
    this.myCustomValue = 1;
    var self = this;
    this.myCustomMethod = function () {
        switch (self.myCustomValue) {

        }
    }
})();
```

`self` can be called whatever you want.

Comment: Am I smoking crack or is there a closing bracket missing at the end? PS: You have also just explained the crazy syntax I couldn’t get my head around in the jQuery library itself with the way it was declared. It makes much more sense on a small object like this example. Thank you my dear sir :-)

Comment: @Maxim, thanks, I added in the paren.  Basically, this syntax is just an anonymous constructor.

Comment: Other popular choices for `self` are `me` and `that`.

Answer (score 2):

You could keep the same syntax if you had a function like this:

```
function patchThis(obj) {
    function patchFunction(orig) {
        return function() {
            return orig.apply(obj, arguments);
        };
    }
    for(var i in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)&&typeof obj[i]=="function") {
            obj[i]=patchFunction(obj[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Then just call `patchThis` on `myCustomObject`.

You can see an example [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/g9ZRS/embedded/).